# jMeter add Cookie in Header Request

Tags: cookies, jmeter

I can't add Cookie in header.

When I try add "Cookie" with value from extractor -> cookie doesn't add to the header request
but when I add "Cookie:" with value from extractor -> I see in header "Cookie:: value"
or when I add "Cookie1" with value -> I see in header "Cookie1: value"

Comment: Hi rafal3290, welcome to StackOverflow! Can you add an [MVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and show your code?

Answer (score 0):

JMeter is super-flexible so there are a lot of ways to add a request header.

I would recommend going for [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager), it should be smart enough to take care of the cookies on its own at the same time providing possibility to add your own cookies if needed.

[image]

References:

- [HTTP cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies)
- [HTTP Cookie Manager Advanced Usage - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-cookie-manager-advanced-usage-a-guide/)